# Touch Pad Detected as PS/2 Generic Mouse on Dell XPS 15 9520 on both Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 11

Tags: 20.04, mouse, dell, touchpad

I can use the trackpad normally on Windows (gestures, sensitivity), but gestures like scrolling on Linux, and the sensitivity is also bad. The mouse is detected as PS/2 Generic mouse on both platforms, but on Windows, "HID-Compliant Touchpad" also shows up in Device Manager under "Human Interface Devices", in addition to PS/2 Generic Mouse under "Mice and Other Pointing Devices".

I've looked through many similar posts, but nothing worked for me.

When I run `xinput list`, I get

```
     Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Privacy Driver                       id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I've tried

1. blacklisting psmouse
2. installing synaptics or libinput
3. `sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse`

Thanks for any help!